# Check password hash created by Django in Flask

Tags: python, flask, passlib

I have a password hash generated by Django.  I want to log in a user with this password hash from Flask.  How can I verify the password in Flask?

```
from django.contrib.auth import hashers
hash = hashers.make_password('pasword')
# pbkdf2_sha256$20000$3RFHVUvhZbu5$llCkkBhVqeh69KSETtH8gK5iTQVy2guwSSyTeGyguxE='

PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)
```

Comment: Please read up on the difference between hashing and encryption (for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms)

Comment: Long story short (with some crazy simplifications): It is hard to get the value back directly from this hash, the typical way is to enter the same password and hash it and see if the hashes are the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [passlib](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/index.html) package to work with password hashes.  It comes with [support for Django's hash format](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.django_std.html).  Your example hash uses `pbkdf2_sha256`, so use the corresponding passlib hash:

```
from passlib.hash import django_pbkdf2_sha256
hash = 'pbkdf2_sha256$20000$3RFHVUvhZbu5$llCkkBhVqeh69KSETtH8gK5iTQVy2guwSSyTeGyguxE='
user_input = 'password'
django_pbkdf2_sha256.verify(user_input, hash)
```

If you want to support multiple formats, [like Django does](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.context-tutorial.html), you can use the pre-configured [Django context](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.context-tutorial.html), or make your own with whatever order is in Django's `PASSWORD_HASHERS`.

```
from passlib.apps import django_context
hash = 'pbkdf2_sha256$20000$3RFHVUvhZbu5$llCkkBhVqeh69KSETtH8gK5iTQVy2guwSSyTeGyguxE='
user_input = 'password'
django_context.verify(user_input, hash)
```